How to apply ant_path_matcher on Spring Cloud Gateway MVC?
I'm migrating from zuul gateway to Spring Cloud Gateway MVC.
But I knew that no more patterns like "/foo/**/bar/**" is allowed since ant_path_mathcer is deprecated.
And I want to keep ant_path_matcher on my Spring Cloud Gateway MVC application.
How can I make it?
I already tried applying "spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher",
and also tried
@Configuration
public class PathMatcherConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }

    @Bean
    public AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher() {
        return new AntPathMatcher();
    }
}

this configuration code, but both way didn't worked.
Here's the error log.

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Invalid mapping pattern detected:
/foo/**/bar/**
^
No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
Action:
Fix this pattern in your application or switch to the legacy parser implementation with 'spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher'.
